# implications of using callr_function = NULL in targets package

Tags: targets-r-package

I was wondering what happens when callr_function = NULL?
Is it just issues with things maybe being in the environment/side effects?

Mainly wondering because I was passing quite large spatio-temporal arrays (0.5 to 5 gigs) and callr serialization via saveRDS is quite slow.

The two things I was thinking about was forking callr and dropping in a different save function or just using callr_function = NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordinarily, `targets` runs the pipeline in a fresh new reproducible external R session. `callr_function = NULL` just says to run the pipeline in the current R session. I only recommend this for debugging because in serious use cases you could accidentally invalidate some targets based on changed data in your global environment. `callr_function = NULL` will probably not help solve issues with large memory. For that, I recommend selecting a more efficient storage format for your data, e.g. tar_target(..., format = "feather"). You could also try tar_option_set(memory = "transient", garbage_collection = TRUE) for better memory efficiency.